# Partial with view modell in layout

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-mvc-partialview

Im not so experienced in MVC and im not sure im really aproaching this the correct MVC way.

I want to have a model for the navigation that renders in a view. This is so that i dont have to clutter the view with logic that renders the links attributes such as href, css and so on.

What is the correct way to render a partial in layout? From what i understand the layout does not use a dedicated controller? The Navigation Model must always be available. Should it be a part of a base class view model that is always called from a base class controller that is always used?

Is there a way to make a helper function that returns the partial navigation view model rendered with the navigation view model?

Comment: You can use `@Html.Action()` in the layout to call a `[ChildActionOnly]` controller method that returns a partial view.